# Is possible add icon in title posts only in specific tag?

Tags: functions, filters, tags, title

I want to add an icon in title posts only in posts with specific tag.

Is this possible?

I've already tried these codes, but they didn't solve my problem:

Approach #1

```
if (is_tag('162')) {
    function new_title( $title ) {
        $new_title = 'icon-url' . $title;
        return $new_title;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'new_title' );
}
```

Approach #2

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'modify_post_title' );
function modify_post_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_tag('162') && $title == 'Existing Title' )
        $title = '<span>Existing</span> Title';
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Comment: if(is_tag('162')){
function new_title( $title ) {
    $new_title = 'icon-url' . $title;
    return $new_title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'new_title' );
}

Comment: add_filter( 'the_title', 'modify_post_title' );
function modify_post_title( $title ) {
 if ( is_tag('162') && $title == 'Existing Title' )
  $title = '<span>Existing</span> Title';
 return $title;}

Comment: OK, and where exactly should that icon be visible? On single post only? On all archive pages?

Comment: In single and archive pages. I have some different posts I want mark in these titles

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first approach is that you check conditional tags too early. `is_tag` will work only after the `$wp_query` is computed, so there is no point in checking it directly in `functions.php` file.

And there is one more problem with both approaches - you use wrong conditional tag...

`is_tag` checks if a Tag archive page is being displayed... So it's not what you're looking for.

And here's a solution:

```
function add_something_to_post_title( $title ) {
    if ( has_tag( 162 ) ) {
        $title = 'something ' . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_something_to_post_title' );
```

Comment: YESSSSSS, yessss yesssssssssssssssssssssssssss, thank you

Comment: Wait I have a problem, the icon shows but it shows in Menu item too, in related post title... I want to show you only in posts title, no menu title. Do you know why?

Comment: Krzysiek Dróżdż do you know how show icon only in posts title? No Menu Item, related post title... etc??